# How do they make Ferengi teeth?

Tags: star-trek, ferengi, makeup

When I'm looking at [Armin Shimerman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Armin_Shimerman) photos, I can see, that his teeth are in nearly perfect condition. Yet, I have never seen any Ferengi with straight, healthy teeth.

Do we have any off-screen information, how do they prepare actors playing Ferengi characters or how do they achieve the effect of Ferengi teeth out of actors having "normal" teeth?

I can see, that Star Trek's make up and characterization department is (was) doing really well, especially when it comes to characters like Morn played by [Mark Allen Shepherd](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_Allen_Shepherd):

[image]

But, even with this evidence, I can imagine how do they get characters with holes in teeth or with triangle-like teeth out of actors having straight, rectangle-like teeth.

Comment: The answer is "false teeth". You can buy a set [here](http://www.dentallab.co.uk/shop/ferengi-teeth/)

Comment: You can see Armin Shimerman putting them in [here](http://starland.com/sf-sc/sf99/images/sf99r2-8.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [interview](http://www.makeupmania.com/blog/interview-with-karen-j-westerfield-emmy-award-winning-makeup-artist/) with Karen Westefield (Senior Makeup Artist for DS9) gives an overview regarding Armin Shimerman's makeup routine

> **Q:** **Take us through a typical day on Deep Space 9.**
>
> **KW:** *On a typical day if Armin is working I have to be there at 4:30am. He
>   arrives at 5:00am. I get a half-hour set up. They give me two hours to
>   do his makeup. First, I apply the prosthetic head and face pieces, do
>   all my edge work and then patch any air bubbles from the foam. I then
>   Pax it and wait until that dries. We take a break for about 5 minutes
>   (I call it the 7th inning stretch), then get back to work. I then
>   paint everything. I usually finish in about 45 minutes. The time might
>   be longer depending on Armin's actions during each episode and the
>   amount of glue. The makeup I do is pretty low maintenance for me and
>   Armin takes good care of it. After his makeup is done, I put powder
>   the face. Armin goes to rehearsal, changes into his costume, then
>   returns to makeup. I then remove the powder and apply KY Jelly to the
>   face. I do his hand makeup, fingernails, **he cleans his false teeth**,
>   and we're off and running.*

---

Interestingly, they seem to have used the same moulds for various different Ferengi teeth

[image]

Comment: The photos are of different Ferengi played by the same actor ([Max Grodénchik](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Grod%C3%A9nchik)), so using the same moulds was an easy way to save money. It might not be possible for different actors to use the same moulds in closeup shots.